# Define bitset size at initialization?

Tags: c++, bitset

I want to make a bitset in C++. I did a bit of research. All examples I found where like this:

```
bitset<6> myBitset;
// do something with it
```

But I don't know the size of the bitset when I define the variable in my class:

```
#include <bitset>
class Test
{
public:
     std::bitset *myBitset;
}
```

This won't compile...

And initializing like this also doesn't work:

```
int size = getDependentSizeForBitset();
myBitset = new bitset<size>();
```

Comment: I have no idea what this is for,  but you could always use a vector<bool> if it won't be too large. This is especially a good option if you're working in an environment which doesn't allow boost (ie. a crappy job).

Comment: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: std::vector<bool> is not only larger, but significantly slower (~5x) in the application that drove me to this question.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Boost has a [`dynamic_bitset`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) you can use.

Alternatively, you can use a `vector<bool>`, which (unfortunately) is specialized to act as a bitset. This causes a lot of confusion, and in general is considered a bad idea. But that's how it works, so if that's what you need, you might as well use it, I suppose.

Comment: +1. It's a shame that vector has that specialization instead of just a separate class all together. It's not like it made it any easier on the vendors to implement it as a specialization: just seems downright silly.

Comment: yep. Unfortunately, I believe the committee has resisted all proposals to deprecate it.

Answer (score 8):

Use [Boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I'm trying to keep my application as simple as possible. So, I'm going for `vector<bool>`. Otherwise I will have to install the extra library...

Comment: Boost::dynamic_bitset is entirely implemented in header files. No extra library to install.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out boosts dynamic_bitset.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying at the beginning is not true. The "examples you found" did not look as you posted. It is impossible to use a non-constant value to parametrize a template. So, your first example is invalid. Only constant expressions can serve as non-type arguments for a template. I.e. the non-type argument has to be a compile-time constant.

Of looks like you want to create a bitset whose size is not a compile-time constant. In this case the `bitset` template is out of question. You need an implementation of run-time sized bitset. For example, you can use `std::vector<bool>` - in many (if not all) implementations this template is specialized to implement a *packed* array of boolean values, where each element occupies one bit (as opposed to an `bool` object).

Answer (score 0):

bitset requires size as a template parameter, meaning the size has to be capable of being determined at compile-time. It cannot be based on a runtime condition, like user input.

For that, you should look into std::vector or boost::dynamic_bitset. std::vector is a specialized template instantiation that uses one bit per element. Unlike bitset, it can be dynamically sized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are solving a coding problem, then one possible idea is: -

1. Define the bitsets with the maximum possible size according to given constraints.
2. Define a bitset "mask" of value ((1 << k) - 1), where 'k' is the desired size.
3. Instead of directly using the bitsets for computation, use (bitsetName & mask)

```
// Suppose the maximum size of bitset according to given constraints is 20
#define bst20 bitset<20>

// Define bitset with value ((1 << k) - 1)
bst20 mask((1 << k) - 1);

// Before computation use '&' operator with mask

// Some examples
map.insert(bitsetName & mask);
print(bitsetName & mask);
```

Answer (score -6):

You can make your class a template to make the `std::bitset` size undetermined until your class gets instantiated. You can do it like this:

```
#include <bitset>

template<int size>
class Test
{
public: 
    std::bitset<size> bitset;
    //...
}
```

Then to use your class you would have to do this:

```
int exampleSize = 42;
Test<exampleSize> name;
```

Comment: Nope. `exampleSize` must be known at compile time.