# How can I pass a constant int via command line argument in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, command-line-arguments, bitset, variable-types

I want to be able to pass an integer via command line argument that I will call length. I need to make this constant, because it will be used to determine the size of several bitsets. I have tried doing this many ways, for example:

```
int main(int arc, const char* argv[]){
        const int * ptr;
        if (!(istringstream{argv[1]} >> ptr)) { return 1;}
        const int length = *ptr;

        bitset<length> right_ones = 1;
        return 0;
}
```

I also tried it this way:

```
int main(int arc, const char* argv[]){
        int test_int;   
        if (!(istringstream{argv[1]} >> test_int)) { return 1;}
        const int length = argv[1];

        bitset<length> right_ones = 1;
        return 0;
}
```

But none of the ways I have tried it worked. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If it's passed via a command line argument, it is obviously not constant.

Comment: Get your DeLorean up to 88 mph. Run the program, observe the user's future input, then go back and add it.

Comment: Templates can only be used with compile time constant. Values passing before running are obviously not compile time constants

Comment: If this is meant to be a compile time constant, why don't you make it a compiler argument (like in a qmake project file, depending what you use) instead of a run time argument?

Comment: A template argument has to be compile-constant and hence can not be derived directly from a runtime value (cmdline argument). If you insist, you could use a switch and instantiate for several compile-time values

Comment: Unless it changes with C++17, you can use `std::vector<bool>`. In ways, it behaves more like a `bitset` than a `vector`, so I recall an intent to change it and introduce a new class to replace the functionality.

Comment: @JamesRoot correct [Why is vector<bool> not a STL container?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17794569/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is going to be passed as a command line argument, then you cannot make it a constant.

By the way, this is relevant to your case: [Define bitset size at initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134718/define-bitset-size-at-initialization)

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood what a const was...Is there anyway to use bitset<length> with length not being constant then? As long as I can pass the size of the bitset via command line my problem will be solved.

Comment: I updated my answer @partyphysics. Read the link for more!

Comment: Thanks, the boost::dynamic_bitset solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

The length of the bitset is needed at compile time so no matter how you try it there is no way to pass that value at runtime.