# Non const size bitset allocation - C++

Tags: c++, constants, bitset

I'm writing a bitmap interpretation program in C++ and I want to use bitset as a buffer. Every bitmap has a different size, so bitset must be allocated dynamically.

> First and the most stupid idea
>
> ```
>    size_t _alloc;
>    std::cin >> _alloc;
>
>    std::bitset<1> *Buff = new std::bitset<1>[_alloc];
> ```
>
> It doesn't make sense because I could use `bool`.

After spending some time searching, I realized that I can use `const_cast`.

> Using `const_cast`.
>
> ```
>    size_t _alloc;
>    std::cin >> _alloc;
>    std::bitset<const_cast<const size_t*>(&_alloc)> Buff;
>    //or
>    std::bitset<(const size_t*)&_alloc> Buff;
> ```

But it doesn't work very well `'this' cannot be used in the constant expression`. Is there any way do allocate bitset with non-const size? If not, Is there any alternative container?
I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define bitset size at initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134718/define-bitset-size-at-initialization) Use `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: What I didn't say, exactly I'm reading pixel array from a bitmap and I wanted store every pixel separately as a bitset with color depth size. For example I have 4-bit bitmap and every loop allocates new std::bitset<4> then it reads those bits and then it converse to RGB value.

Comment: I do not understand how is it related to the problem. If you convert some values to RGB, why bother with using bitset at all.

Comment: I tried vector<bool> and it was slower a bit. dynamic_bitset should be ok, Thanks!